# ESP-IDF ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed. ninja failed with exit code 1

Tags: esp-idf

I am trying start working with ESP-IDF. Using get started guide I am trying to execute the basic hello_world program from examples but while flashing I am getting below error.
Can anyone suggest me how to solve this error.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you opened it in a simple terminal, instead of the terminal shortcuts provided by ESP-IDF. Go to your IDF install location, and run .\export.bat in a terminal. That should load everything you need to build the code inside that particular terminal.

On a side note, I have run into similar issues so many times on Windows, it is very frustrating. Linux is a much better option for setting up ESP-IDF and its tools.

Comment: Hi Usman, Thanks for the reply. Its worked for me. My basic hello world programming working now. Thanks for the suggestion.